# Secure access to my private Blockchain

Tags: security

I have a private blockchain based on EOS. I would like to know, know how to secure all access to the EOS blockchain using an account. I'm talking about access to APIs that could give information or modify the blockchain configuration.

Exemple

API that changes configuration : http://localhost:8888/v1/producer/pause

API that get information :http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/get_info

So I would like to secure my blockchain, only companies that have an account in the blockchain can have access to these APIs.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by putting proxy ahead of nodeos or using firewall. Nodeos doesn't have options for doing this.